# How do I insert the results of several commands on a file as part of my sed stream?

Tags: string, bash, sed, string-formatting

I use DJing software on linux (xwax) which uses a 'scanning' script ([visible here](http://pastebin.com/ySf9wCTb)) that compiles all the music files available to the software and outputs a string which contains a path to the filename and then the title of the mp3. For example, if it scans path-to-mp3/Artist - Test.mp3, it will spit out a string like so:

```
path-to-mp3/Artist - Test.mp3[tab]Artist - Test
```

I have tagged all my mp3s with BPM information via the id3v2 tool and have a commandline method for extracting that information as follows:

```
id3v2 -l name-of-mp3.mp3 | grep TBPM | cut -D: -f2
```

That spits out JUST the numerical BPM to me. What I'd like to do is prepend the BPM number from the above command as part of the xwax scanning script, but I'm not sure how to insert that command in the midst of the [script](http://pastebin.com/ySf9wCTb). What I'd want it to generate is:

```
path-to-mp3/Artist - Test.mp3[tab][bpm]Artist - Test
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to prepend the BPM number *to*?

Comment: Sorry to be unclear. The xwax scanner script (see the link) outputs the file path and then a formatted file name. For example, if it scanned Jump.mp3, it would output "path-to-mp3/Jump.mp3[tab]Jump" - I'd like to add my bpm to the formatted file name, right after the tab. e.g. "path-to-mp3/Jump.mp3[tab][bpm]Jump".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me *where* in that script you want to insert the BPM number, but the idea is this:

- To embed the output of one command into the arguments of another, you can use the "command substitution" notation `` `...` `` or `$(...)`. For example, this:

  ```
  rm $(echo abcd)
  ```

  runs the command `echo abcd` and substitutes its output (`abcd`) into the overall command; so that's equivalent to just `rm abcd`. It will remove the file named `abcd`.
- The above doesn't work inside single-quotes. If you want, you can just put it outside quotes, as I did in the above example; but it's generally safer to put it inside double-quotes (so as to prevent some unwanted postprocessing). Either of these:

  ```
  rm "$(echo abcd)"
  rm "a$(echo bc)d"
  ```

  will remove the file named `abcd`.
- In your case, you need to embed the command substitution into the middle of an argument that's mostly single-quoted. You can do that by simply putting the single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings right next to each other with no space in between, so that Bash will combine them into a single argument. (This also works with unquoted strings.) For example, either of these:

  ```
  rm a"$(echo bc)"d
  rm 'a'"$(echo bc)"'d'
  ```

  will remove the file named `abcd`.

---

**Edited to add:** O.K., I think I understand what you're trying to do. You have a command that either (1) outputs out all the files in a specified directory (and any subdirectories and so on), one per line, or (2) outputs the contents of a file, where the contents of that file is a list of files, one per line. So in either case, it's outputting a list of files, one per line. And you're piping that list into this command:

```
sed -n '
{
# /[<num>[.]] <artist> - <title>.ext
s:/\([0-9]\+.\? \+\)\?\([^/]*\) \+- \+\([^/]*\)\.[A-Z0-9]*$:\0\t\2\t\3:pi
t

# /<artist> - <album>[/(Disc|Side) <name>]/[<ABnum>[.]] <title>.ext
s:/\([^/]*\) \+- \+\([^/]*\)\(/\(disc\|side\) [0-9A-Z][^/]*\)\?/\([A-H]\?[A0-9]\?[0-9].\? \+\)\?\([^/]*\)\.[A-Z0-9]*$:\0\t\1\t\6:pi
t

# /[<ABnum>[.]] <name>.ext
s:/\([A-H]\?[A0-9]\?[0-9].\? \+\)\?\([^/]*\)\.[A-Z0-9]*$:\0\t\t\2:pi
}
'
```

which runs a `sed` script over that list. What you want is for all of the replacement-strings to change from `\0\t...` to `\0\tBPM\t...`, where `BPM` is the BPM number computed from your command. Right? And you need to compute that BPM number separately for each file, so instead of relying on `sed`s implicit line-by-line looping, you need to handle the looping yourself, and process one line at a time. Right?

So, you should change the above command to this:

```
while read -r LINE ; do # loop over the lines, saving each one as "$LINE"
    BPM=$(id3v2 -l "$LINE" | grep TBPM | cut -D: -f2) # save BPM as "$BPM"
    sed -n '
    {
    # /[<num>[.]] <artist> - <title>.ext
    s:/\([0-9]\+.\? \+\)\?\([^/]*\) \+- \+\([^/]*\)\.[A-Z0-9]*$:\0\t'"$BPM"'\t\2\t\3:pi
    t

    # /<artist> - <album>[/(Disc|Side) <name>]/[<ABnum>[.]] <title>.ext
    s:/\([^/]*\) \+- \+\([^/]*\)\(/\(disc\|side\) [0-9A-Z][^/]*\)\?/\([A-H]\?[A0-9]\?[0-9].\? \+\)\?\([^/]*\)\.[A-Z0-9]*$:\0\t'"$BPM"'\t\1\t\6:pi
    t

    # /[<ABnum>[.]] <name>.ext
    s:/\([A-H]\?[A0-9]\?[0-9].\? \+\)\?\([^/]*\)\.[A-Z0-9]*$:\0\t'"$BPM"'\t\t\2:pi
    }
    ' <<<"$LINE" # take $LINE as input, rather than reading more lines
done
```

(where the only change to the `sed` script itself was to insert `'"$BPM"'\t` in a few places to switch from single-quoting to double-quoting, then insert the BPM, then switch back to single-quoting and add a tab).

Comment: That's useful - I've used `...` but never $(...), however I'm still struggling to solve my issue. I think the script (http://pastebin.com/ySf9wCTb) needs to get more complicated. Right now, it says 'generate a big list and use sed to format it,' but I think I need to make it do something more like 'for every file you find, generate String A (my bpm) off on the side, then use sed to format a string which uses String A in the midst of it. Sorry, I'm quite a novice bash-er and programmer, so it's a struggle for me to describe it in anything but practical terms.

Comment: @Pebby: O.K., I think I see what you need. I'll update my answer (but it'll take me a few minutes).

Comment: @Pebby: I've updated my answer. Please confirm that I've correctly understood everything.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the stray 'id3v2' in there - that was my fat fingers when I pastebinned it. Just read through your updated answer and took a stab at implementing it. While I understand the script you provided, I think I'm missing something. It does, indeed, seem to be embedding the BPM variable mid-sed, but it only executes the loop once. Here's what I've got at http://pastebin.com/LeX6XXpp - I know I'm missing something to make it iterate on every line of the 'find'. I added the 'echo' line just to verify what I was seeing, and my limited understanding of | in linux makes that make sense.

Comment: @Pebby: Sorry, I messed up: I never changed the `sed` command to use `$LINE` as its input, so the `read` command reads the first line and then the `sed` script just reads the rest of them, all within the first loop iteration. I'll re-update my answer.

Comment: Getting there! it seems like it wants to read each word of each line (filenames with spaces are triggering id3v2 multiple times), rather than each line - do you know what I'm missing? http://pastebin.com/2HHqGctb

Comment: @Pebby: That's because you need to write `"$LINE"` rather than `$LINE`. (Sorry, I don't know why I wrote `name-of-mp3.mp3`; that was unhelpful of me.)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help, and I have a few leads for things to research now in case I want to do more like this down the road (had no idea about reading the results of a find line-by-line - very useful!). I'm going to share this information with the xwax mailing list in case any of the other DJs find this helpful. You've certainly made my life on stage better. :)